# What can cause this condensation pattern in a window's glass?

Tags: everyday-life, humidity, condensation, fractals

What can cause a condensation pattern like this one:

[image: Condensation Pattern]

in a kitchen's window? Found early in the morning. Adjacent windows had an homogeneous condensation "pattern" all over the surface.

Glass had been cleaned several times with normal window cleaner.

Best hypothesis is that the previous home owner had some kind of humidity measure sticker there?

It is not in a place where one would stick something for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439053/geometric-condensation-patterns-on-windshield

Comment: @BobaFit, I don't think so. The pattern clearly resembles a snowflake, so I still bet on a human-made sticker or similar, maybe even from manufacturing time?